# How to use `Map` type in Pigeon

Tags: flutter, pigeon

How can I specify a type in Pigeon to be a Map (e.g. `Map<String, String>`), and preferably a Map with dynamic value types (`Map<String, dynamic>`. I can't know for sure what type the `data` values are until the push message is sent.

### Attempt 1

I've tried to define a class using:

```dart
class RemoteMessage {
  Notification? notification;
  Map<String, dynamic>? data;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error message:

```sh
Error: pigeons/push.dart:6: Generic type arguments must be nullable in field "data" in class "RemoteMessage".
Error: pigeons/push.dart:6: Generic type arguments must be nullable in field "data" in class "RemoteMessage".
```

### Attempt 2

I also tried making `dynamic` optional as well:

```dart
class RemoteMessage {
  Notification? notification;
  Map<String, dynamic?>? data;
}
```

In that case, I get only 1 instance of the error:

```sh
Error: pigeons/push.dart:6: Generic type arguments must be nullable in field "data" in class "RemoteMessage".
```

### Attempt 3

If I make the **key** type optional, i.e. `Map<String?, dynamic>? data;`, I get the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = './android/app/src/main/java/dev/flutter/pigeon/Pigeon.java' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
pub finished with exit code 255
```

### Summary

It looks like Pigeon doesn't support `Map` or `dynamic`, although it should already support generics: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63468.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of issues on Flutter ([1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94689#issuecomment-988502757) and [2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94828#event-5736553430)), where Stuart Morgan (a developer from Google probably working on Dart / Pigeon) gave me some help, I realized that my class should look like:

```dart
class RemoteMessage {
  Notification? notification;
  Map<String?, Object?>? data;
}
```

Key takeaways:

- I **should use `Object` instead of `dynamic`**, because Pigeon otherwise generates **broken** code in Java, Objective-C and Dart. This is a bug I reported in [Pigeon: using dynamic generates code...](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94828):

  - **Dart:** `dynamic.decode()`
  - **Objective-C:** `@property(nonatomic, strong, nullable) NSDictionary<NSString *, dynamic *> * data;`
  - **Java:** `public void setData(Map<String, dynamic> setterArg) { this.data = setterArg; }`
- and because as documented, Pigeon **doesn't currently support non-null** types, I should use `?` for all types, including using `String?` as the type for Map key instead of `String`: `Map<String?, Object?>`.